# Take current rotation or coordinates as zero?

Tags: objects, properties, coordinates

Let's say I have object rotated at 19 degrees and I want to keep current rotation, but I need to see 0 in rotation field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'Apply' function to apply the current location, rotation or scale to make that the new 'zero' by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and selecting the element you want to apply.